# Detect when id retrieved from php query is changed

Tags: php

I'm running a query where I'm getting the average score of a student, by getting the average score of an activity type(quiz,exams,etc.) and multiplying it to its assigned grade percentage(ex: 80 *.03).

I've grouped the result by its `activity_ID` and `Student ID`.

To get the Grade of the student I need to add the score of each activity type. by simple adding all the result of each activity type.
(ex:grade =10.40+30+12;)

Now my problem is when the student ID is changed the result of the previous student is added to the result of the new one.
(ex:new student grade = previous result, plus his own)

I want to detect when the Student ID is changed inside the

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $studentID_link = $row['studentID']; 
    $atName = $row['AT_name']; 
    $GLOBALS['AR_Score'] = $row['AVG(AR.Score)']; 
    $AT_gradePercentage =$row['AT_gradePercentage']; 
    $AT_gradePercentage /=100; 
    $periodGrades = $AR_Score*$AT_gradePercentage; 
    $variableName = $variableName + $periodGrades; 
}
```

Comment: Right, so that is hardly rocket science now is it. Here at SO we are more than willing to help other developers with problem, **but we dont write your code for you**. Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi sorry, this is my  code.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 {$studentID_link = $row['studentID'];

   $atName = $row['AT_name'];
   $GLOBALS['AR_Score'] =  $row['AVG(AR.Score)'];

   $AT_gradePercentage =$row['AT_gradePercentage'];
   $AT_gradePercentage /=100;
   
   $periodGrades = $AR_Score*$AT_gradePercentage;
   $variableName = $variableName + $periodGrades;
 }

Comment: Can you read that code? Please post that code in your question, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49116434/edit) link below your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc()
```

Check for the id after storing the initial student id in a temp variable outside of the loop. Compare each new row's student ID to the previously stored temporary id. Also declare an array outside of the loop and use

```
array_push()
```

to push each total onto the array. Use an associative array with the student ID as the key and avoid using array_push if you are accessing student IDs out of order or use an index in mysql to allieviate this issue.

Honestly, you may want to reexamine your sql or show us if you want us to rewrite the code for you.

Update:
If the current mysqli_fetch_array is fetching an associative array, you can leave it, however refer to my above suggestions if you are having issues with that.

```
$curr_student = NULL;
$array = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $studentID_link = $row['studentID']; 
    if($curr_student === NULL || $curr_student !== $studentID_link){

    $curr_student = $studentID_link;
    if(!array_key_exists($curr_student, $array))   $array[$curr_student] = 0; 

    }

    $atName = $row['AT_name']; 
    $GLOBALS['AR_Score'] = $row['AVG(AR.Score)']; 
    $AT_gradePercentage =$row['AT_gradePercentage']; 
    $AT_gradePercentage /=100; 
    $periodGrades = $AR_Score*$AT_gradePercentage; 
    $array[$curr_student] = $array[$curr_student] + $periodGrades; 


}
```

I'm not certain about your global array and how you are using it, but this should work to add your students into each array member regardless of random access of student ID.

Comment: OP has posted some code now. You could give a more specific answer now

Comment: @David, thanks for the code.
I'm having an error message " Undefined offset: " based on the error message, it is near 


if(!$array[$curr_student])$array[$curr_student] = 0; this expression.


Sorry for the trouble, I'm really new in using PHP.
Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sure that when I'm typing my reply I've used a lot of new lines to make my comment more readable, but it always appears like that.
And I can't find any button to attach a screen shot of my code in the comment, Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Use array_key_exists


http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

in place of !array

Comment: @DavidKamer, Thank you so much!!, your a life saver.